# How to change the commas to dot when I cannot find the comma

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

For me this is a bit strange as I am trying to feed this into my app:

```
"https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=37.751&lon=-0.854&detailLat=36.751&detailLon=-0.854&width=650&height=450&zoom=10&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1";
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to insert my own latitude and longitude and is using this code to do so:

```
url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=";
    url += latitude;
    url += "&lon=";
    url += longitude;
    url += "&detailLat=";
    url += latitude;
    url += "&detailLon=";
    url += longitude;
    url += "&width=650&height=450";
    url += "&zoom=10";
    url += "&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1";
```

I have done it this way as I try to identify where the problem is.

When I print the url I get this:

```
https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=37.752&lon=-0.854&detailLat=37.752&detailLon=-0.854&width=650&height=450&zoom=10&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1
```

In this print I get no commas in the lat and lon:

```
lat=37.752
lon=-0.854
detailLat=37.752
detailLon=-0.854
```

So far all is good. However, when I upload the app via Xcode I can see this in the Xcode log:

```
https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=37,752&lon=-0,854&detailLat=37,752&detailLon=-0,854&width=650&height=450&zoom=10&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1
```

Here the commas surface:

```
lat=37,752
lon=-0,854
detailLat=37,752
detailLon=-0,854
```

Here is the essential code I use to setup the latitude and longitude:

```
latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.x, 3).ToString();
longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.y, 3).ToString();
//latitude = Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.x.ToString();
//longitude = Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.ToString();
```

I have tried to find the comma in the unity output but not succeeded.

Again it works perfectly when I hard code the latitude and longitude but Xcode generates commas when I add the latitude and longitude as above.

Here is the whole code:

```
public class Radar : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject pnl_Background;
public TMP_Text txt_TitleRadar;
public Button btn_RadarGoBack;
public TMP_Text txt_RadarInfo;
private string latitude;
private string longitude;


private string url;

public WellWebView WebView;
public RectTransform image;


private void Start()
{
    SetColors();

    if (Utility.setup_List[0].isLocations)
    {
        switch (Utility.processLocationBtnNr)
        {
            case 1:
                txt_RadarInfo.text = Utility.setup_List[0].locationName1 + ", " + Utility.setup_List[0].countryName1;
                latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation1.x, 3).ToString();
                longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation1.y, 3).ToString();
                break;
            case 2:
                txt_RadarInfo.text = Utility.setup_List[0].locationName2 + ", " + Utility.setup_List[0].countryName2;
                latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation2.x, 3).ToString();
                longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation2.y, 3).ToString();
                break;
            case 3:
                txt_RadarInfo.text = Utility.setup_List[0].locationName3 + ", " + Utility.setup_List[0].countryName3;
                latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation3.x, 3).ToString();
                longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation3.y, 3).ToString();
                break;
            case 4:
                txt_RadarInfo.text = Utility.setup_List[0].locationName4 + ", " + Utility.setup_List[0].countryName4;
                latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation4.x, 3).ToString();
                longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].setLocation4.y, 3).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        txt_RadarInfo.text = Utility.setup_List[0].freqLocationName1 + ", " + Utility.setup_List[0].freqCountry;
        latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.x, 3).ToString();
        longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.y, 3).ToString();
        //latitude = Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.x.ToString();
        //longitude = Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.ToString();
    }

    //url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&detailLat=" + latitude + "&detailLon=" + longitude + "&width=800&height=1224&zoom=8&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1";

    //url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=37.751&lon=-0.854&detailLat=36.751&detailLon=-0.854&width=650&height=450&zoom=10&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1";
    //     https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=37.752&lon=-0.854&detailLat=37.752&detailLon=-0.854&width=650&height=450&zoom=10&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1



    url = "https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=";
    url += latitude;
    url += "&lon=";
    url += longitude;
    url += "&detailLat=";
    url += latitude;
    url += "&detailLon=";
    url += longitude;
    url += "&width=650&height=450";
    url += "&zoom=10";
    url += "&level=surface&overlay=radar&product=radar&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1";

    print(url);

    //print("#" + url.IndexOf(','));

    StartRadar();
}

void StartRadar()
{
    WellWebView.SetAllowJavaScript(true);
    WellWebView.SetJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    WebView = WellWebView.CreateWebView();

    WebView.OnFinishedInit += (RaisedWebView) =>
    {
        // The web view is fully initialized, and you can call the web view methods
        WebView.FullScreen = false;
        WebView.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        WebView.SetTargetRect(image);
        WebView.Android.SetUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebView.Android.SetLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        WebView.IOS.AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures(true);
        WebView.LoadUrl(url);
        WebView.Show();
    };
    WebView.Init();
}

void SetColors()
{
    pnl_Background.GetComponent<Image>().color = Utility.backgroundColor;
    txt_TitleRadar.color = Utility.foregroundColor;
    txt_RadarInfo.color = Utility.foregroundColor;
    btn_RadarGoBack.image.color = Utility.foregroundColor;
}


public void BTN_RadarGoBack()
{
    WebView.StopLoading();
    WebView.Destroy();
    SceneManager.LoadScene("WeatherList");
}
```

}

BTW I use the Unity asset WellWebView to display the radar map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to your `.ToString()` method.

```
latitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.x, 3).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
longitude = Math.Round((decimal)Utility.setup_List[0].freqSetLocation1.y, 3).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I should have thought about that I guess and I tried your suggestion and unfortunately got the same result with commas in Xcode: LONGITUDE: -0,854 | LATITUDE: 37,752

Comment: He he I just added the ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) to the existing tostring by mistake. It now works and I am an idiot that did not test this. THANKS: